# Modify onClick attribute via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add more functionality to an already rendered button code.
The only way to do it is Javascript since it's rendered before from the server and I only have access to the JSP.

Here is what I have now, but it's not working, it just displays the same message twice. And if I click the button, the alert "hello" is not shown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEventBefore(element, type, fn) {
  var old = element['on' + type] || function() {};
  element['on' + type] = function () { fn(); old(); };
}

function sayHello(){
  alert('hello');
}

var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].getAttribute("name") == "Complete"){
    var theclick = arr[i].getAttribute("onClick");
    alert(theclick);
    addEventBefore(arr[i], 'Click', sayHello);
    var theclick2 = arr[i].getAttribute("onClick");
    alert(theclick2);
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the rendered source code of the page:

```
<td valign='top' align='right' >
 <button  name="Complete"  title="The complete Button"
 onClick="document.forms.TaskInfoPage.action='http://prodserver:8080/Approval.jsp?windowId=dd4c0&eventTarget=stepApproval&eventName=Complete'
 document.forms.InfoPage.submit();return false;">Complete</button>
</td>
```

So, I want to place the sayHello() before it does the action on the onClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `onclick` rather than `onClick`, so you need this:

```
addEventBefore(arr[i], 'click', sayHello);
                     // ^ lower case here
```

The attribute itself still isn't going to display anything different, but the event themselves will work, [you can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yTYt6/1/). Also, to maintain `this` for your event handlers, I recommend you at least [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the functions, like this:

```
function addEventBefore(element, type, fn) {
  var old = element['on' + type] || function() {};
  element['on' + type] = function () { fn.call(this); old.call(this); };
}
```

Comment: I tried with `onclick` first and got the same result, then I tried `onClick`;  Gonna try the call()